# Code Sensing is overzealous

Tags: support, markdown

This is in reference to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36988645/1036361):

It seems the code detection algorithm is a bit overzealous.

When posting the output from GDB, the algorithm said that this is code and **must** be treated as such.

That's fine; however, I surrounded the block in `<pre>` block, because GDB output simply isn't code, and it still was not accepted.

Comment: No it's not, there's no "code sensing" to begin with.  It just picks the most popular tag with a language set to use by default.

Comment: @davidism "Your post appears to contain code which is not formatted as code" is always really annoying, but not the same issue in the OP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply post it as code and tell it not to add syntax highlighting.

From the [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting):

> To specify that you don't want any syntax highlighting for a code block, use:
>
> `<!-- language: lang-none -->`